# Ruby on rails search in serialized array through the checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, serialization

Hi I have a rails app in which i am storing the tags in the serialized form

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

serialize :product_keywords, Array

scope :with_tag, lambda { |tag|

                  where(["product_keywords LIKE ?", "%"+tag.join("%")+"%"])

                 }

end
```

in the view i have

```
<% Product.all.active.each do |product| %>

                  <% product.product_keywords.map do |keywords| %>
                          <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                              <%= check_box_tag("with_tag[]", keywords, false) %> <%= keywords.capitalize %>
                            </label>
                         </div>                 
                  <% end %>
              <% end %>
```

here when i find the product with the tags which are coming in the array from the checkbox from the scope `with_tag` it only fetches the record based on the last checkbox checked

you can get a clear vision by the query occuring

```
product_keywords LIKE '%tshirt%printed%'
```

the product_keywords are stored in the array on the table.

how can i find the records if the multiple repetitive tags are stored in the products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `LIKE` You should generate `product_keywords LIKE "%#{tag}%"` for every tag.

Finally yor should join them with `SQL` '`OR`' or '`AND`' depending on situation (any tag matching - use `OR`, all tags matching - use `AND`)

Assuming you want to have 'AND' you can easily iterate over all tags to set scope, something like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :product_keywords, Array
  scope :with_tag, lambda { |tag| where(["product_keywords LIKE ?", "%#{tag}%") }
end
```

usage

```
# we have selected tags in tags
products = Product.all
tags.each { |tag| products = products.with_tag(tag) }
```

this will generate where condition for each tag. Many where conditions are joined in AR by sql 'AND'

example sql output for tags set to ['tshirt', 'printed']

```
... WHERE product_keywords LIKE "%tshirt%" AND product_keywords LIKE "%printed%"
```

If you want to 'OR' the tags conditions (matching any) you should build the full SQL where clause, for example:

```
scope :with_any_tag, lambda { |tags|
  # build SQL stmt for all tags, i.e.
  # (product_keywords LIKE ?) OR (product_keywords LIKE ?)
  # replace 'OR' with 'AND' if you need all-matching instead of any-matching
  sql_stmt = tags.collect { |tag| "(product_keywords LIKE ?)" }.join(' OR ')

  # prepare sql placeholder values, i.e.
  # %tsrhit%, %printed%
  sql_placeholders = tags.collect {|tag| "%#{tag}%"}

  # pass conditions and placeholders to where as a list
  # first param is a stmt, then all placeholders
  where([sql_stmt] + sql_placeholders) 
}
```

This is more general solution, as you can change `OR` to `AND` and vice-versa, depending on the situation.

And then use it this way:

```
products = Product.with_any_tag(['tshirt', 'printed'])
```